# Java code understanding

Tags: java

Hi I am a bit new to programming and recently I have been given a piece of code that I must understand of a monopoly game written in Java.

I have never tried to understand someone else's code so naturally I don't even know where to start.

My boss asked me after I understand the code and it's functionality to reproduce it.Easier said than done since the game has about 3000 lines of code.

I have tried to start from the main class but this seems to be getting me nowhere because I keep being sent to a dozen different classes.

What I wanted to ask is if there is a software that shows what pieces of code are running during the time the game is turned on.

If such software doesn't exist, where in the code do you guys recommend me to start and what tips can you give me to make this go well?

Comment: Try netbeans or Eclipse.

Comment: jdb (Java Debugger) allows you to set breakpoints and look at the state of variables at those points.

Comment: Then what is problem? Netbeans has built-in this ability.

Comment: the problem is i only 2 months since i learned my first programming language with is java i understand the basic OOP principles but thats about as far as my java language knoledge goes and programming

Comment: Trust me the problem is your boss. Ask a css guy to code in Java without any Java background... Always the same things, when stupid people think that computer science can be learn in 2 days by a 5 years old boy... btw: you have good answers of how to start, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the code. 3000 lines is really few. Read from top down, if there is a foreign class, CTRL+click on it, then read it too from top to down, then click ALT+LEFT, which takes you back to the previous (main) class.

Or you can create UML diagrams in (for example) NetBeans.

Or debug your code step-by-step to see where it runs.

(*But it bugs me... How come you have a boss - hence a job - as a programmer if you don't know what a debugger is?*)

Comment: I have only started to learn programming 3 months ago and I've only done HTML/CSS development java was something my boss asked me to learn on my own sorry if the question was to trivial

Comment: @user985482 your boss is stupid, he should hire a java developer, it is not the same job as css/html

Comment: Wow, understanding a java monopoly game when you only know html and don't even know what a debugger is... Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are looking for a *debugger*, provided by most IDEs.  They will let you run the code one line at a time and "see what happens".

Comment: Try this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370072/recomend-a-standalone-java-debugger

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you understand the Java programming language and how typical Java applications are structured, compiled and deployed. Get a good Java book (*Effective Java* comes to mind) and start learning!

Comment: @DJClayworth: Please explain. Referring to a good book can't hurt, no?

Comment: If you don't understand Java basics and syntax then you won't get much out of Effective Java. It doesn't make it a bad book.

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading the javadoc comments of the classes and methods. Try to understand the role of each class in the application. Classes and methods should have meaningful names (Player, Location, Dice, whatever). Then start from the main method and see what it does.

A monopoly game must have some kind of loop, and at each iteration, the next player changes its location, executes some action, which changes the state of the game.

Answer (score 0):

i think this software exists ... it's usualy called IDE ... run or better said .. debug your code ... set break points and run your code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you may also have a look at UML of the app. The better IDEs let you view the diagrams of what you're working with. NetBeans used to let you do that, not sure if it's possible with the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

If possible have a play with the application to make sure you have some understanding of what it's doing and what some of the concepts are. (eg. Oh, it has the concept of players, with money, and a board and real-estate. There's some kind of dice thing. The players can buy real-estate. And sell it. And mortgage it. And use it to charge rent to other players. etc.)

If you're lucky the code will have been written a) cleanly, and b) with adequate (and useful!) comments. If you're really lucky they'll be [javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comments.

Before jumping in and looking at the code through your debugger it's worth spending some time becoming familiar with how all of the pieces fit together. In particular looking at any objects and the relationships between them, and what they represent.
Even if there are no javadoc comments I can recommend running a tool like [doxygen](http://doxygen.org/) (coupled with [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/)) over the code. This can provide easy to navigate class diagrams to help you get a feel for the pieces. (Others here have mentioned that Netbeans will generate UML class diagrams which would also be suitable)

Once you understand the relationships between the classes you're in a position to start trying to understand how the code actually works. Use the navigation features of your IDE or the doxygen documents, whichever is the most natural for you. Any time that you spend arguing with your tools is a distraction from trying to understand what you're reading.

Only after you have understood the code will you get anything meaningful out of using your debugger. Hopefully you'll find that you don't need it at all.